# Hook into the rendering of a WordPress Template

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have to use WordPress as some meta templating system and include some `JSP` snipptes which will be evaluated later with Tomcat after rendering the page statically. But naturally the `JSP` Code could not be interpreted by the php parser. This results in plain text strings mixed with the interpreted template parts.

**Is there any way to hook into the (pre) rendering of a WordPress Template?**

I need way get access the rendered template so i can strip out the `JSP`-Tags. Maybe wrapped between some unique tags or something else. But this ist not part of this question.

### Example

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<render:jsp>
    <%= request.getParameter("title") %>
</render:jsp>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't quite follow your use case. If you don't want these tags in generated page source then why are you including them in template?

Comment: @Rarst Actually it's quite simple. I've a CMS and a Java application running on Tomcat. The CMS -WordPress- must generate static HTML with some `JSP` fragments which are needed by the Java application to work properly. The Client should be able to view the CMS part without being interrupted by not rendered `JSP` snippets.

Comment: So you are using same output for two distinctly different purposes? Why not just generate different content for users and Java app?

Comment: Yes. Because this is our use case :) It's one application consisting two parts. One Part is generating jsp enhanced static content for the other one which works with the jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but WP doesn't offer you the possibility to do it in a nice way, so you have to use  output buffering.

Something like:

```
// before template is included
add_action('template_redirect', function(){

  // you can do some checks here
  // perhaps you need this only a certain page?
  if(!is_home())
    return;

  // capture output from here on...
  ob_start(function($html){

    // this function runs after the capture ends,
    // you can replace your tags here 
    $html = strtr($html, array(
      '<render:jsp>'  => '<!--',
      '</render:jsp>' => '-->',
    ));

    return $html;

  });

});
```

The contents of the buffer are automatically sent by PHP to the output just before the script finishes execution.

Comment: Works as expected.